# Changing IP Address of ZTE CDMA 1x USB modem

Tags: networking, modem, ip-address, windows-networking

My Reliance Netconnect ZTE CDMA 1x USB modem has a static IP address. I want to change it, but through `ipconfig` it's not getting changed.

How can I change it, then?

Answer (score 1):

> My Reliance Netconnect ZTE CDMA 1x USB modem has a static IP address

Static external/public IP address?  Static internal/private IP address?  You mean the IP address you get from your Internet Service Provider is static?  Is that the one you are talking about?  If so, you need to call your ISP and ask them to change it, since they are the ones giving it to you.  This address is not determined by the modem.  In fact, you are most likely paying more money just to have the static IP address.  You can have them give you a cheaper dynamic IP address which will then change every few days.

Comment: dynamic IP addresses dont change every few days.  They dont often change at all.  They just arent guaranteed to be the same.